# How do I pass variables between two different python scripts I have

Tags: python, variables, import, module

I'm trying to pass information between two different python scripts. They're quite long, so for simplification purposes, here are two other scripts where I encounter the same issue:

a.py

```
f = open('test.txt', 'w+')
num = int(raw_input('How many are there: '))
tipe = raw_input('What kind are they: ')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from b import fxn

    for x in xrange(num, num+11):
        fxn()
        num = x

    f.close()
```

b.py

```
from a import num, tipe

def fxn():  
    print num, tipe
    f.writelines(str(num)+', '+tipe)
```

I am asked for num and tipe twice, then the entries from the second time are printed 11 times.

How can I make it so the variables/files in a.py are passed to b.py, edited/opedned/manipulated in b.py, then passed back to/closed in a.py?

Also, why am I asked for num and tipe twice, then the code under if **name** == '**main**': is run?

Comment: Functions can take parameters. The reason you're asked for input twice is those IO operations are in the global scope and will get executed every time you import a.

Answer (score 0):

When passing variables between Python scripts, remember that when you call a script, the calling script can access the namespace of the called script.

That being said, you could give this a try: Start the called script with the code

```
from __main__ import *
```

This grants access to the namespace (variables and functions) of the caller script. Since these are not actually the files you will be manipulating as you said earlier I will leave it to you to apply this to the real files, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass them through functions

**a.py**

```
f = open('test.txt', 'w+')
num = int(raw_input('How many are there: '))
tipe = raw_input('What kind are they: ')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from b import fxn

    for x in xrange(num, num+11):
        fxn(num, tipe, f) # Pass parameters num, tipe and file handle
        num = x

    f.close()
```

**b.py**

```
# from a import num, tipe --> **This is not required**

# receive inputs
def fxn(num, tipe, f): 
    print num, tipe
    f.writelines(str(num)+', '+tipe)
```

Executing a.py will result in

```
3 fruits
3 fruits
4 fruits
5 fruits
6 fruits
7 fruits
8 fruits
9 fruits
10 fruits
11 fruits
12 fruits
```

3 fruits prints twice because you are calling function first and then you are increasing num (by re-assigning). Instead you can have your **a.py as below to have 3 fruits printed only once:**

```
f = open('test.txt', 'w+')
num = int(raw_input('How many are there: '))
tipe = raw_input('What kind are they: ')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from b import fxn

    for x in xrange(num, num+11):
        fxn(x, tipe, f) # Pass parameters num, tipe and file handle

    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way.

**a.py**

```
x=5
print x
```

**b.py**

```
import a
print a.x
```

Comment: if I run 'import a'  it executes entire script 'a'